# Redirect subdomain whatever the request is to another domain using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I had a website where there was a button that creates a random picture and add it to *../wf/pix/random-name.png*

So for example you'd go on *create.my-domain.com* and click a button to have a random picture generated at *create.domain.com/create/wf/pix/random-name.png*

But now I want to redirect all the traffic to another domain.. so I want requests like:-

- *create.domain.com/create/wf/pix/random-name1.png*
- *create.domain.com/create/wf/pix*
- *create.domain.com/create/wf*
- *create.domain.com/create*
- *create.domain.com*

to redirect to *domain2.com*

How could I do that with `htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I thing might work..please check ..
RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} create.domain\.com\create\wf\pix\ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure RewriteEngine On

```
# BEGIN Redirect
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} create.domain\.com\create\wf\pix\ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yes I have.. here's what I've done so far and got it to work... I have used cPanel subdomain redirect and it created the htaccess file for me and then I recreated the folders and put htaccess file in each of them.. but there has to be a better, smarter way...

Comment: Did you want the directory style to be the same in each domain or did you want all images in the root of the new domain